# the value of checkbox stays true when unchecked

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have 5 checkboxes, one of them is set to true by default others false. I collect user decision in a list and then i perform an action and clear the list in the constructor. However the checkbox that has value to true by default is in the list even if i uncheck it. So i select one item and the list should contain only one but it contaits the one that is set to true and the one i selected so two. I would clear the list before each selection but i need the list to hold more possibilities.
xaml

```
<Checkbox  x:Name="AllCheckBox"
IsChecked="{Binding FilterAllItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
HorizontalOptions="Start" />
<Checkbox  x:Name="AllCheckBox"
IsChecked="{Binding FilterBeginnerItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
HorizontalOptions="Start" />

View Model

 private bool _filterAllItems =  true;
private bool _filterBeginnerItems = false;

  public bool FilterAllItems
        {
            set
            {

                _filterAllItems = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterAllItems");
                if (FilterAllItems == true)
                {
                    FilterBeginnerItems = false;

                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = -1);

                }
           }
            get => _filterAllItems;
        }
 public bool FilterBeginnerItems
        {
            set
            {

                _filterBeginnerItems = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterBeginnerItems");

                if (_filterBeginnerItems == true)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;

                    UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);

                }

            }
            get => _filterBeginnerItems;
        }
   public FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(INavigation navigation)
            : base()
        {

            Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForArticlesAndCategories()).Wait();

            FilterItemsCommand = new Command(async () => navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered()));
            UserDecision.Clear();

        }
```

What should i do?

Comment: Why did you set `FilterBeginnerItems` to false one more time in set method? It will always false in your demo .

Comment: because i want it to uncheck automatically once user selects FilterAll

Comment: It's not a good design . If you put the binding source in a list , you should put the picker in a ListView .

Comment: I am sorry, i dont really understand. I am not using picker i am using checkbox

Comment: Post the full code and the effect which you want achieve (like screen shot)..

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4htabriud2zd93t/.vs.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213694/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-vanessa-kensington).

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had checked your sample and you could improve the code in `FilterViewModel` like following

```
public  bool FilterAllItems
        {
            set
            {

                _filterAllItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (FilterAllItems == false)
                {
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }
                }

                if (FilterAllItems == true)
                {
                    FilterBeginnerItems = false;
                    FilterIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterUpperIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterAdvancedItems = false;
                    if (!UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = -1);
                    }


                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId=1))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 1);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 2))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 2);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 3))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 3);
                    }
                    if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = 4))
                    {
                        UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = 4);
                    }

                }

            }
            get => _filterAllItems;
        }
```

And in other source like `FilterBeginnerItems`

```
set
{
  _filterBeginnerItems = value;
   OnPropertyChanged();

   if (_filterBeginnerItems)
   {
       FilterAllItems = false;
       UserDecision.Add(_parentCategoryId = 1);
       if (UserDecision.Contains(_parentCategoryId = -1))
       {
           UserDecision.Remove(_parentCategoryId = -1);
       }

    }

}
```

Your issue are very similar with the last thread . @Leon's answer is correct and you could check it .